# Problem uploading to storage in locating the image

Tags: java, android

```
ImageZipper(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()))
        .setQuality(50)
        .setMaxWidth(300)
        .setMaxHeight(300)
        .compressToFile(file);
```

this cody

```
if (filePath!=null){
    try {
        File file = new File(filePath.getPath());
        File imageZipperFile=new ImageZipper(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()))
                .setQuality(50)
                .setMaxWidth(300)
                .setMaxHeight(300)
                .compressToFile(file);
        Uri IndividualImage = Uri.fromFile(imageZipperFile);
        StorageReference ImageFolder = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("imageUser");
        String itme=String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        final StorageReference ImageName = ImageFolder.child("AD" + itme);
        ImageName.putFile(IndividualImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                ImageName.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        String url = String.valueOf(uri);
                        if (addUser.getSection_us().isEmpty()){
                            addUser.setSection_us(addUser.getPhoto());
                        }
                        addUser.setPhoto(url);
                        SaveUser();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("errror1010", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

} else {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This message

```
D/errror1010: /document/image:2147: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:2147: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:2147: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

If you modify the code in this way it works correctly

```
StorageReference ImageFolder = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("imageUser");
String itme=String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
final StorageReference ImageName = ImageFolder.child("AD" + itme);
ImageName.putFile(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        ImageName.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                String url = String.valueOf(uri);
                if (addUser.getSection_us().isEmpty()){
                    addUser.setSection_us(addUser.getPhoto());
                }
                addUser.setPhoto(url);
                SaveUser();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 18
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `D/errror1010: /document/image:2147: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` Indeed as that is not a valid file system path to begin with. That is last part of a content scheme that you obtained somewhere. You should use the content scheme. The obtained uri directly.

Comment: `E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:2147: ` ??? Where are you using BitmapFactory?

Comment: `Problem uploading to storage` Can you tell what you are trying to upload and to what kind of storage? Its so vague your subject. Further you did not tell what your problem was. So we have to guess.